# ReGex to filter a list of URLs in a spreadsheet

Tags: regex, excel

Disclosure: me as I'm a newbie in these topics.

**Is it possible to filter a number of URL rows in a spreadsheet using regex?**

*Quick story short:* I have a list of URLs (.spreadsheet) and a list of regex functions which I'd like to use to filter and retrieve the URLs.

*Long Version:* I have a list of URLs of a website which are spread across several servers. And then, a list of regex expressions that each define the kind/format of URL that is hosted on each server.  What I'm trying to do is to map the URLs of the site to the server they are hosted. *

That's all I have. Two lists. One of all URLs, one of the regex rules that define the server they belong. Do you suggest a quicker/easier way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have access to any other tools besides Excel, such as Notepad++?  Yes, you may use regex to filter/screen URLs.

Comment: Write a UDF with a static RegEx object that takes a string to test and a pattern to use as the parameters.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes, I've used notepad++ before, how would I do this?

Comment: @Jeeped I'm afraid I'm not that advanced. I don't even know what is a UDF.

Comment: For more context @TimBiegeleisen I have a list of regex expressions and each represent the format/strings of URLs hosted a server. And then, another entire list of URLs of a website which are spread across several servers. What I'm trying to do is to map all these URLs of the site to the server they are hosted. However, that's all I have. Two lists. One of all URLs, one of the regex rules that define the server they belong. Does this give a better idea of what I'm trying to achieve and helps on a recommendation/suggestion of how to address this? thanks

Comment: @Jeeped any further thoughts on this?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen any further thoughts on this?

Comment: Post some sample data and the expected outcome.